# How to fill rectangle in c# using bounding boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cognitive-services

I have listed bounding boxes  X top left, Y top left , X top right , Y top right, X bottom right , Y bottom right , X bottom left , Y bottom left

Need to create fill rectangle on image.

How can i calculate x,y,width and height for Rectangle

Have used Pen and DrawRectangle

```
 Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageFilePath);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
 Pen snowPen = new Pen(Color.Black, width);
 g.DrawRectangle(snowPen, x , y , width, height);
```

How can i convert the boundingboxes data to get x,y,height and width ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of `DrawRectangle` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawRectangle_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_System_Single_) to know how are expressed x and y:

> The x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.
>
> The y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.

And based on the fact that you mentioned that your input info is:
`X top left, Y top left, X top right, Y top right, X bottom right , Y bottom right , X bottom left , Y bottom left`

Then:

- x= X top left
- y= Y top left
- Height= (Y top left - Y bottom left) or Y top right - Y bottom right: if you have a boundingbox value which was a rectangle, the values are equals)
- Width= (X top right - X top left) or X bottom right - X bottom left: if you have a boundingbox value which was a rectangle, the values are equals)

Remarks:

- As you did not mention how your boundingbox values were expressed (int? float?), keep in mind that here your values should be int values.
- If your bounding box is not a rectangle, you should use `DrawPolygon` instead